# Fill areas in a matrice

Tags: matlab, image-processing, graphics

[image]

As u can see in this figure, I have 3 "lines", that are not linear with values of zeros (or NaNs) in between.

What I would like to create a picture that has 3 filled areas with a single value by averaging all the values in the "line" section" and fill them where the area of zeroes below.

averaging is not a problem and also using a fill or patch command is not the problem, my problem here is how to identify a piece of data here that is not linear or homogenous in it's content by it's shape and efficiently create three slices of data because real values in the matrice must stay.

will appreciate any idea!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tough to tell from a colormap like that, but it looks like the inhomogeneities are considerably worse along the columns.  If that is the case, then you may be best off comparing the values of each column to the two adjacent ones and creating a bias index.

Just taking a stab at it - I'll use `inhomoge` as slang for your inhomogenous image

```
predictedInhomoge=(inhomoge(1:end-2)+inhomoge(3:end))/2;
biasImage=(predictedInhomoge-inhomoge(2:end-1))./(inhomoge(2:end-1)+predictedInhomoge);
image(255*biasImage/max(biasImage(:)));
```

If your blue colored data are actually zeros and not just small values the biasImage above will have a lot of pointless `Inf` values.  If that's the case, just drop the denominator off of the biasImage equation so that it is no longer normalized.

```
biasImage=(predictedInhomoge-inhomoge(2:end-1));
```

If the biasImage looks like the highest values reflect your inhomogeneities then you're in business, just pick a threshold and recalculate the values above it.  If it doesn't, then I'd consider trying something Bayesian.

Probably doesn't need to be said, but any NaNs are easy to find and remove.

Comment: In my case, the values represent real data that I need to average and not a 255 colormap

Comment: Ah I see, your new question wording is much clear - I was correcting away the "bad data" areas within those lines (which you should consider doing anyway, since they are clearly extant).  Anyway, see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f0-8778.html) for a tutorial on image segmentation in Matlab.  Yes it is working with images, but images are just 2d arrays and once you have the indices of the points to include in each "line" taking a mean of just those is simple.